# Java JNDI in Tomcat: BeanCreationException / NamingException on global Resource. Looking for the same class that global resource returns

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, jndi, c3p0

I don't understand what can cause a Bean creation exception on behalf to return the same class as required.

The class is `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`, and the error says that *was expected to **return** an instance of [**com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource**] but **returned** an instance of [**com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource**]*

This is the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceGCA' defined in class path resource [META-INF/xxxxx-security-app.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: 
The local resource link [dataSourceGCA2] that refers to global resource [jdbc/dataSourceGCA2Global] was expected to return an instance of [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource] but returned an instance of [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]
```

I'm using Java 7 and Tomcat 7.

This is the config of datasource:

In *context.xml*:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/dataSourceGCA2"
  global="jdbc/dataSourceGCA2Global"
  auth="Container"
  type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" />
```

In *server.xml*:

```
<Resource description="whatever"
  name="jdbc/dataSourceGCA2Global"
  auth="Container"
  factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
  type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
  user="xxxxxxxx"
  password="xxxxxxxx"
  initialPoolSize="1"
  minPoolSize="1"
  maxPoolSize="5"
  acquireIncrement="1"
  driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
  jdbcUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@tprodva2:1522/BD2"
  testConnectionOnCheckin="true"
  idleConnectionTestPeriod="300"
  maxIdleTimeExcessConnections="0"
  maxIdleTime="0" />
```

What can cause this behaviour?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(was gonna comment but I have too little reputation)

This can be caused by the same class being loaded by two different classloaders.

Comment: Some kind of collission?

Comment: Two classloaders load the same class definition and produce two different `Class` objects that do not equal; instances of either cannot be assigned to the other. Its just a suspicion though.

Comment: You drove me to the solution!!! Thanks. My problem was the hibernate dependency depended from another version of c3p0 that the tomcat already had. I excluded the c3p0 jar and worked.

Comment: Good to hear! In case you’re using maven, the maven-enforcer-plugin might help you with recognizing problems like that